# Variable Types compatible with glGetFloatv

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++-2010

What variable types are compatible with opengl's glGetFloat() or glGetFloatv()?

P.S. This is in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic type you want to use is `GLfloat`. This matches the type in the function prototype. This is a 32-bit float value, which mostly matches the `float` type, but this is not guaranteed.

For cases where `glGetFloatv()` returns a single value, you can simply use the address of a `GLfloat` variable. For example:

```
GLfloat val;
glGetFloatv(GL_DEPTH_CLEAR_VALUE, &val);
```

For cases that return multiple values, you can either use an array:

```
GLfloat vals[4];
glGetFloatv(GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE, vals);
```

Or, to make it more C++, a `vector`:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> vals(4);
glGetFloatv(GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE, &vals[0]);
```

Or, even nicer in C++11:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> vals(4);
glGetFloatv(GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE, vals.data());
```